# reversing word with capital at the beginning and number at the end

Tags: javascript

i got this function to reverse word, which is worked correctly but the problem come when that word have number on it, example : Test1

```js
const reverseWords = param => param.split(' ').map(word => [...word].reverse().map((letter, i, arr) => {
  let opposite = arr[arr.length - i - 1];
  return opposite.toUpperCase() === opposite ? letter.toUpperCase() : letter.toLowerCase();
}).join('')).join(' ');

console.log(reverseWords('I am A Great human Test1'));
```

expected output

> I ma A Taerg namuh 1tset

my output

> I ma A Taerg namuh 1tseT

whats is the solution please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in a test to see if the opposite character is a letter. It looks like you only want to capitalize if the opposite character is currently lowercased *and* is a letter.

```js
const reverseWords = param => param.split(' ').map(word => [...word].reverse().map((letter, i, arr) => {
    const opposite = arr[arr.length - i - 1];
    const opIsLetter = /[a-z]/i.test(opposite);
    return opposite.toUpperCase() === opposite && opIsLetter
      ? letter.toUpperCase()
      : letter.toLowerCase();
}).join('')).join(' ');

console.log(reverseWords('I am A Great human Test1'));
```

```css
I ma A Taerg namuh 1tset
```